# How to share directory between VM and docker on same machine in opensuse?

Tags: linux, docker, virtual-machine, opensuse, shared-directory

I know how to have a shared directory between docker and host and even VM and host, is there a way to directly share a directory between VM and the Docker in OpenSUSE, I am using virtual machine manager for the VM. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer
assign a tag to the VM filesystem(add file system from the "add hardware" option provided in the VM assign a string to it i.e. TAGNAME)

use the command inside the VM:

```
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,rw TAGNAME /MOUNT_POINT
```

And to make this directory permanently appear after every boot, edit the /etc/fstab , add this line at the end.

```
TAG   /MOUNT_POINT    9p  trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,rw    0   0
```

To make the folder available from docker just use the `-v` option during docker creation and specify the same folder as source. This solves the problem. :)

Comment: "declared a shared folder between host and VM " as I mentioned. Good feedback +1

Answer (score 0):

The [bind mount (-v or --mount)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) should apply within a VM as it does from a Host, in order to share a folder to your Docker container.

I do that all the time between a KVM and Docker container on SLES 12SP3 (not OpenSuse, but close)

Comment: sorry, my bad actually the docker doesn't sit inside the VM, I have OpenSUSE as the host OS and on that Virtual machine present along with the docker on the same host OS.

Comment: @LakshmikanthB Then you need to  make sure your VM has declared a shared folder between host and VM (same host folder that is mounted in your docker container)